# Hide HTML elements from specific devices

Tags: html, ipad, mobile, hide

I want to hide some HTML elements on a page for specific devices, so I can optimize the page structure when I look at it on iPad rather than PC..

To hide some DIVs on iPad, I gave the element a specific class ("x1") then used this CSS:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  {

    div.x1 { 
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

And it worked, however I can't emulate the same on a PC version.. how can I hide things from PC only views?

Comment: Use @media only screen and (min-device-width : 1024px) then it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below media query for only desktop

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1024px) {
    div.x1 { 
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solved this process it on the backend side.
IF you are using php there is function `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` so you can know what kind of device is accessing your page.[PHP get browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)